# SQLite database access on Xamarin.form

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin

I'm pretty new to SQLite, and I'm trying to get a string from a SQLite database. But I'm unable to return people.Name because people is an AsyncTableQuery. Any ideas?

This is the code:

```
readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

public string GetNameByID(int id)
{
    var people = from t in _database.Table<Model>() where t.ID == id select t;

    return people.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the `AsyncTableQuery` defined, you can take it to a `List` via `ToListAsync`

Example:

```
var people = from t in _database.Table<Model>() where t.ID == id select t;
await people.ToListAsync();
foreach (var person in people)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```